# How can I get jpg's to list in IIS as thumbnails instead of hyperlinks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a directory with directorybrowsing enabled which lists the files successfully but what I want is to list them as thumbnails (for the pictures ). Can this be accomplished in IIS configuration or must I to it with server side code? I'm using asp.net.

Comment: Write your own http module for iis7 or isapi for iis6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using IIS 7+ take a look at [this Module](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1325) for IIS. This will only work for integrated pipeline mode since this plugin interfere with IIS request handling pipeline. You dont need to do extra coding if you can use this.

http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1325